# SQL using REPLACE on one of many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM MailingList
```

There are about 20+ columns in the **MailingList** table, one which is called **Address**. This column has some fields which contain commas, which I need to take out. So I updated my query to:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Address, ',', '') AS Address, * FROM MailingList
```

But now I have two **Address** columns. Is there a way to only display one **Address** column while still using the wildcard (*) for all the other columns?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't call it "AddressNoCommas" or something similar?

Comment: Best practice is to avoid select * and to select EXACTLY the columns you need. SSMS scripts for you the Sql query easily. With *, no you can't have one address but with the correct way of selecting columns you can.

Comment: I have often wished for this, but its probably not a good idea...  What I do is use SSMS, select top 1000 to generate my select list and replace the columns in question.  In your case replace the address field with your replace statement.  At least that saves all the typing.  If you do not like the format you can create a stored procedure to return the select list in the format you choose.

Comment: Select * is great when we want to check something is a database. But in an application could lead to serious performance issues and bugs (in case someone else add a column to the table, etc )

Comment: Didn't think there was a way, but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way to do this, though listing the columns you want explicitly is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can trick as following query:

> 1. Get the data into a temp table
> 2. Drop the cloumns that are not needed
> 3. Get results and drop temp table

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(Address, ',', '') AS Address2
INTO   #TempTable
FROM   MailingList

ALTER TABLE #TempTable
    DROP COLUMN [Address]

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shadow - avoid using the * wild card if you can...

I know listing out ALL of the columns in select statement for big tables is a pain so here is a quick short cut you may not be aware of:  In SQL Server Management Studio, browse through the object explorer and find the table you want to select from (MailingList).  Right-click it to view the context menu and choose "Script Table as" then "SELECT TO" then "New Query Editor Window".  This will create a new select statement with each column spelled out.  In the future, use this method to create select statements, queries, procedures, etc. rather then the * wildcard.  Performance is better and it just looks nicer :-)

Then you can solve your alias issue with the replace function.